# Two players coin flipping

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Two players are flipping a coin. If head, player A wins 1 point. If
>   tail, player B wins 1 point. The person who first wins 2 points wins
>   the game. The loser must pay the winner $\$1$.
>
> However, if player A has an option he can use to increase the stake of
>   the game to $\$2$-game, what is the value of such option?

I received this question during an interview but I am unsure of the answer I provided.

The original game has an EV of $0$ and using the option will yield an EV of $0.25$ according to my calculations. The final answer will then be that the option has a value of $0.25$ USD.

Is this way of reasoning correct? Can anybody provide a thorough explanation of the process and show me the right way of approaching this problem?

Comment: The "option" is not clear.  When can it be exercised?  At the start, the game appears to have expectation $0$ at either $\$1$ or $\$2$ so if it  can only be exercised before the game starts, it is worth $0$.

Comment: You mean he can choose to exercise his option when he is a point ahead, but before he has won?

Comment: The probability of winning for player A is higher after a head has been tossed, P(W|1H) = 2/3, so I thought that it was most sensible to exercise the option only in that case. The interviewer did not provide any additional detail.

Comment: @almagest Exactly, that should be right

Comment: In my opinion the increased expected value is $ 0.5\cdot 0+0.5\cdot 1=0.5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning looks correct to me. There is a 0.5 chance of a H on the first throw. In that event A exercises the option. If the next throw is H he wins 2. If the next throw is T, then his expected win is 0.

On the other hand, there is a 0.5 chance of a T on the first throw. In that event, A does not exercise the option. If the next throw is T he loses 1. If the next throw is H, then his expected win is 0.

So adding that up, with the option his expected win is $0.25\times2-0,25\times1=0.25$, compared with an expected win of 0 without the option. So the option is worth 0.25.

Note that A the only time A benefits from exercising the option is immediately after a H on the first throw. If there is a head and he delays, then either there is a H on the next throw and it is too late - the game is over - or there is a T on the next throw and he has no advantage. Similarly, if there is a T on the first throw his position is worse, so it hurts him to exercise the option.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on whether A pays for the right to have the option (whether he uses it or not) or if A pays only for using the option. In the first case you are right. In the second (it seems more likely, at least to me) the value is a bit higher.
To clarify this in the first scenario a game could go as follows:
Game starts. Player A pays 0.25$ \$ $ for the option.
Coin flipped - B wins.
Coin flipped - B wins.
A pays 1$\$ $.
In total A loses 1.25$\$ $

In the second scenario:
Game starts.
Coin flipped - B wins.
Coin flipped - B wins.
A pays 1$\$ $.
In total A loses 1$\$ $,

He doesn't pay the 0.25$\$ $ since he didn't use the option to raise the bet.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on what you are implying with this second scenario (A paying only for using the option)?

Comment: @Bruh I edited the answer to expand on what I meant

Comment: Now i understand, thank you. This second scenario assumes that the options doesn't need to be purchased but it's there for A to be exercised, but the exercise has a cost. My question is now: how would you estimate the cost of exercise of the option without knowing it beforehand?  @shortmanikos

Comment: @Bruh Since the option will only be used when A wins the first flip, you basically take it for granted that A wins the first flip. Comparing his EV (when we know he won the first toss) with and without the option gives us the value.

Comment: Sure, but I was interested in deriving the different value of the option in this second scenario.

If we draw a tree subtracting X from each final payoff on all the branches following the first flip being a H and not subtracting anything from those following a T we should arrive to an EV = 1/4 - 1/2X. In order to calculate the maximum value of the "embedded option" we set the EV=0 and solve for X, resulting in X = 1/2. As stated by @shortmanikos the cost of the option in this case (paying just for the exercise of the option)  is indeed higher than in the previous case.